# Nested for loop for grid traversal

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, range, time-complexity

I have an n*n grid network where each node has the value (0,0),(0,1)...(n-1,n-1). I need to add an edge so that the average path length(APL) of the network reduces. In order to do that I have to select each node, draw an edge to every other node and check the APL.

So I made a nested for loop for this:

```
for x,y in itertools.product(range(n), range(n)):
    for i,j in itertools.product(range(x,n), range(n)):
```

Here the outer for loop selects the first node and the inner for loop selects the second node. `range(x,n)` reduces the number of iterations somewhat, similarly is there a way to change `range(n)` in the inner for loop to something else such that the number of iterations can be reduced?

I tried using `range((y+1)%n,n)` but it won't work because, suppose first node is (0,n-1), then after selecting the second node as (0,n), it won't select (1,0). So is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: Can you restrict attention to connected components? It seems that you will never want to add an edge between to nodes that are not already connected indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just use the modulus on the index vs the loop.
Loop through the same indices twice and just `continue` on the same index, e.g.:

```
for x, y in itertools.product(range(n), repeat=2):
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(n), repeat=2):
        if (x, y) == (i, j):
            continue
        add_edge((x, y), ((x+i)%n, (y+j)%n))
        ...
```

Comment: Actually my code is working fine but for large values of n(15,20,etc..) it is taking days to execute it. I tried your code and compared it's execution time with mine by giving a few small values of n, and your code is taking longer to execute.

Comment: If your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it, you might find better luck at [codereview.se]. Remember to read [their requirements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.